# method .gsub not returning desired string

Tags: ruby

I have a method that sorts a vector of strings alphabetically and returns the first string with "***" inbetween each substring.

```
def two_sort(s)
  x = s.split.sort_by(&:downcase).first
  return x.gsub(//, '***')  
end
```

1. The problem the '***' is appearing before the string and after the string. I only want it inbetween the letters. How is this done with regex?
2. Also, Why am I getting this error undefined method split when it works in my terminal?

.

```
`two_sort': undefined method `split' for #<Array:0x005635bb9bdb78> (NoMethodError)
from `block in <main>'
from `block in describe'
from  `measure'
from  `describe'
from  `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input and desired output. And what do you mean by vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve it is to [split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-split) `x` into characters then [join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-join) them back using `'***'` as separator:

```
def two_sort(s)
  x = s.split.sort_by(&:downcase).first
  x.split(//).join('***')
end
```

You can even combine the two lines and get rid of the temporary variable `x` to let it be more in the spirit of Ruby:

```
def two_sort(s)
  s.split.sort_by(&:downcase).first.split(//).join('***')
end
```

As @gerry suggests in a comment, [`String#chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-chars) can be used instead of `split(//)`. I think it is slightly faster and it looks even easier to read:

```
def two_sort(s)
  s.split.sort_by(&:downcase).first.chars.join('***')
end
```

But for large input strings, [`String#chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-chars) requires a lot of allocations for 1-char strings and it is probably slower and requires more memory than `x.gsub(//, '***').sub(/\A\*\*\*/, '').sub(/\*\*\*\z/, '')` (suggested by @m-simon-borg).

@cary-swoveland kept his mind clear and suggested the cleanest and fastest way to remove the leading and trailing `***`: `x.sub(//,'***')[3..-4]`.

#### Conclusion

I think the fastest solution (that also uses the smallest amount of memory) is:

```
def two_sort(s)
  s.split.sort_by(&:downcase).first.gsub(//, '***')[3...-3]
end
```

Comment: This. Since this answer is going to be the best here, please remove `return` from the last line, it’s considered to be a code smell.

Comment: This works too `x.gsub(//, '***').sub(/\A\*\*\*/, '').sub(/\*\*\*\z/, '')`. Not sure which would be more performant for a large string, but it uses only `sub || gsub` and regex as was originally asked

Comment: You could use `chars` instead of `split(//)`.

Comment: @m.simonborg I suspect yours works better for large strings. Splitting requires a lot of allocations for small strings.

Comment: If you just want to strip three characters from the beginning and end of `x.sub(//,'***')`, `x.sub(//,'***')[3..-4]` is simple and clear.